# How to toggle "over" style on a button in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to create a menu using `TextButton`. The menu should be accessible by mouse and keyboard. For the correct hovering behaviour, I set the style as usual:

```
TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.GRAY);
textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
textButtonStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
```

This works fine with mouse (the `over` style is toggled when the mouse is hovering). However, I want to be able to select a menu item by keyboard. The "currently selected" menu item should be selectable using the arrow keys and `enter` should confirm the item.

The keyboard interaction is not an issue here, but setting the "highlighted" mode on the button. I imagine selecting a button using the keyboard should behave the same as hovering over it with a mouse. But it looks like there is no way of "toggling" the state of the button using the API. There is an `isOver()` method, but no `setOver()` method.

Any ideas? Do I really have to create two styles and switch them out with `setStyle()`? I would consider that ugly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to programmatically make the button think that it has been hovered upon, send an `InputEvent` with type `enter` which signifies that the mouse has entered onto the button:

```
InputEvent event = new InputEvent();
event.setType(InputEvent.Type.enter);
event.setPointer(-1);
button.fire(event);
```

Use the `exit` `InputEvent` for defocusing it:

```
InputEvent event = new InputEvent();
event.setType(InputEvent.Type.exit);
event.setPointer(-1);
button.fire(event);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom class for your actor and override your isOver method to return isFocused || super.isOver()

By the way, you might take a look at https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-controllerutils/wiki/Button-operable-Scene2d for not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the easiest what you can do is just to retrieve the desired button style right from your skin and apply this to the button like this:

```
Skin skin = getYourSkin(); // or even button.getSkin() I believe should also work
button.setStyle(skin.get(styleName, ButtonStyle.class));
```

This way you don't need to create a style but you can just get it from your skin definition